# Performance of different javascript for loops

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

According to tests with [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/for-loop-checks/3) a for loop in javascript with this form:

```
for (var i = 0, item; item = itemsArray[i++];){
   item = Math.random();
}
```

is several orders of magnitude faster than a typical for loop, even in older browsers like IE8. I have not been able to find another reference to this loop construct and am wondering why is it so much faster?

Also, I've looked through the sources of some javascript libraries, like [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src) and [Knockoutjs](https://github.com/knockout/knockout) and they do not use this construct in their code.

Which leads me to be suspicious.  If this form of looping is so much faster, why don't popular libraries, written by people much smarter, use it?

Am I missing something where this loop is not as good as it looks on the surface?

Comment: What do you consider a "typical for loop"? And why do you overwrite the `item`?

Comment: Because much smarter people spot the bug and don't use this buggy code ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I missing something where this loop is not as good as it looks on the surface?

Everytime a single `item` from your `itemsArray` is falsy, your condition fails to do what is expected.

Actually that's also the reason why your test says it would be much faster, that's just because it doesn't even do the first iteration as `itemsArray[0] = 0`. An [updated jsperf](http://jsperf.com/for-loop-checks/5) which iterates `[1..1001]` shows that the for loops perform quite similar, yours actually being one of the little slower ones.

> why don't popular libraries, written by people much smarter, use it?

They focus on good algorithms, readability, usability, cross-browser-support (and of course correctness), not about micro-optimisation.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew I was missing something and I just couldn't see it.  I had seen this loop in a couple other jsperfs and it caught my interest , but I knew it was too good to be true.

Answer (score 0):

There are less operations i guess, using .length in loop is slow, it does not check for stuff like i < len either. It does only verify item return true to go on looping (which may cause severe issue if any of your item exist but return false)

I guess library don't use this cause it's inelegant, less readable, and may cause the issue mentioned above  ? It's not a bullet-proof loop.